# Point specific users to a specific form in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am building a small database for 5 people. I am not a guru in Access but I can find my way around. I just need help with making the login form I created only open the individual form for each individual user. Below is the code I have so far. Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()

'Check that User is selected
If IsNull(Me.CboUserID) Then
    MsgBox "You need to select a user!", vbCritical
    Me.CboUserID.SetFocus
Else

        DoCmd.OpenForm "[UserID]" = "CboUserID '"
        Me.Visible = False

        MsgBox "Password does not match, please re-enter!", vbOKOnly Or vbExclamation
        Me.txtPassword = Null
        Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx, you will see you are missing a form name. In addition, the Where statement should either be `"[UserID]= " & Me.CboUserID` or `"[UserID]= '" & Me.CboUserID & "'"`

Comment: cleaned it up a bit , but the where statement keeps giving me an error that the form name is wrong

Comment: What is the name of your form? This `"[UserID]" = "CboUserID '"` can never be correct.

Comment: its multiple forms for multiple users ,

Comment: What is the outline name of any form you wish to use? Examples, please.

Comment: Example of form name is  'TyoungForm' , error i get is " the Form name [UserID] = 'Tyoung' is Misspelled or refers to a form that doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

The name of the form is the username & form, so:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm Me.CboUserID & "Form"
```

I think it is not sensible to work with multiple forms - forms can be filtered and adjusted so that only one is necessary.